# How to access an image stored on the SD card?

Tags: camera

I have captured an image using USB camera module and it is stored on the SD card (on Raspberry Pi). How to access the image?

I need to view the image on the screen using some commands.

I am very very new to Raspberry Pi. Kindly suggest me.

Comment: On what screen? Are you working directly on Raspberry Pi, or want to display it on another computer?

Comment: well yes, on my PC.

Comment: How do you connect to Raspberry Pi? Via SSH?

Comment: yes. Through SSH.

Comment: I used this command. But this is not working.                                                           sudo apt-get install fbi                                                                                          sudo fbi -d /dev/fb0 -a -T 2 0001.jpg

Comment: You would use `fbi` to display it on the monitor attached to the Pi directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transfer the file to your local PC. You can do it with `scp` command which accepts the same login credentials as `ssh`.

For example, if you connect to the Pi with `ssh pi@mypi` and saved the image to user `pi` home directory, execute

```
scp pi@mypi:~/0001.jpg .
```

This will copy the file `/home/pi/0001.jpg` on the Pi to the current directory on your local system.

Then you can open with your local application.

Comment: ok, now i need to replace the mypi with the login ID ryt??

Comment: @navs Yes, same as with `ssh`; followed by a colon and a path to the file.

Comment: yes. i have entered that command. (it asked for passward) .But my question is where to view that image? It only displays some text after the image file name.( 100%   1.9Kb/s   0.0 ). I really dont have idea about how to access the contents in the sd card. ( I have started working with Rsp from yesterday).

Comment: Locally on your PC. You have said not a word, if you are using Windows, Mac, Ubuntu, or anything. Nevertheless, it's a simple JPG and your questions are getting less and less Raspberry Pi-related.

Comment: sorry!  I  am using windows and yes it's a simple JPG. is it possible to view the image captured at that moment ( or stored in sd card on Rsp) with a single command? or do we need to install any software for that?  and the USB camera module which ever I am using is compatible with Rasp 3.

Comment: *"It only displays some text after the image file name.( 100% 1.9Kb/s 0.0 )"* -> Yes, that is `scp` indicating it has downloaded the image from the Pi to your PC.  You can view it however you like there now.

Comment: yes. I got it. thank you so much @ techraf ,@ goldilocks